# How to use the inner class of MainActivity in another Service class

Tags: android

In my app `MainActivity` contains inner Class called `ListIcon`.The `ListIcon` extends `ArrayAdapter<Drawable>`,now I want to use this `ListIcon` class in another Service class `Window`.

My `Window` class contains `ListView`. The adapter for `ListView` is class `ListIcon` like this:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this)
MainActivity.ListIcon main;
main=new MainActivity.new ListIcon(this);
listView.setAdapter(main);
```

This is not working properly. It is not importing `ListIcon` class properly I think.Is it possible to send the `ListIcon` class to  service class using intent.

Comment: It's hardly good practice to create inner classes in your Activity classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity {

    public static class ListIcon{ //Inner class with static

    }  

}
```

## My Window class contains ListView.The adapter for ListView is class ListIcon like this:

```
ListView listView =new ListView(this)

MainActivity.ListIcon main;

main=new MainActivity.ListIcon(this); //It should be like this

listView.setAdapter(main);
```

Comment: I have tried this way it gives me red line saying "MainActivity is not an enclosing class"

Comment: if I make my class static some of its function will not work

Comment: Yes that may be possible depends on requirements so it'll be good if you will create common class for adapter.